# magento 2.4.6 install extention

Tags: extensions, magento2.4.6

i am new working with magento 2. i have build a website with magento 1 and there it was possible to install extensions very easy.

now i have learned by doing it, i have to use the SSH (i use putty) and i have to put in some command lines.

Firts i downloaded the extension zip file. i have the files and folders in my magento installation set on rights 775. then i extracted the zip file in the folder  "app" and "pub" folder.
then i used the next command codes in Puttys:

- ~/public_html/bin/magento setup:upgrade

I got at the end this massege: Could not validate a connection to the OpenSearch. No alive nodes found in your                                                                                                              cluster

- ~/public_html/bin/magento setup:static-content:deplo                                                                                                             y -f
- ~/public_html/bin/magento indexer:reindex

Then when i was googling the problem i found a command line for updating the db-schema. so i give it a try. but didnt have the positive effect.

but still after trying these things i get the following massage on my website:

```
{"0":"Please upgrade your database: Run \"bin\/magento setup:upgrade\" from the Magento root directory.\nThe following modules are outdated:\nET_Base data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0\nET_Theme data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0","1":"#1 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:23]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:116]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:23]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:264]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:41]\n","url":"\/admin\/","script_name":"\/index.php","report_id":"f2ef3380ba4b48f9faa3643b9ac5a2ff737d554cd16096ad4ead4ff49d816018"}
```

i hope someone can help me with this problem. or maybe explain me how i can install extensions in a better way. it looks like every time i google it or on youtube i seem to miss something.

thanks a lot

greets,

Comment: hi poeple, I still have problems with installing extentions. i cant figure it out why it won't work. is there someone that has some time to take a look with me and maybe explaine some things to me. maybe with is zoom connection. i am dutch and also live in the netherlands and it would be great if there are some dutch people if not it is also good :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Please follow the steps for installation-

1. Unzip the respective extension zip
2. Create Vendor and module name folder inside your Magento2/app/code/ directory
3. Move all module's files into magento root directory Magento2/app/code/Vendor/Module/ folder.
4. Run Following Command via terminal

   php bin/magento s:up
   php bin/magento s:d:c
   php bin/magento s:s:d -f
5. Flush the cache and reindex all.

   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   php bin/magento c:f
6. Now module is properly installed

Comment: YES! Finally I had time for it again and it finally worked! installed the extension and the background and the website still work.

just strange that when I select the theme, the website no longer works. I then get the following error code that {"0":"Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed","1":"#1 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Design\\Fallback\\Rule\\Theme->getPatternDirs( and much more lines.

Comment: @joel thanks for your feedback

Comment: new feedback.. i did not extract the files into main directory. so now i did and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue was coming due to the elastic search Please restart the elastic search and try again to run same command.

And for the module installation purpose I think there is no need to put to module in the pub folder. It will automatic put needed files after running the s:s:d -f command.